# Output of top into text file, but ranked by memory

Tags: linux, memory, top-command

I would like to put up a batch script that include a step where I want to output the results of command "top" in Linux to a text file. There is one catch here though, I would like to rank the top results by memory usage. I know it is easy when you have the command windows (Shift+F and n will do the trick) but I have not found any possible solution to do so in a bash script.

Could you help? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a ~/.toprc with `W` in top after `Shift+F` and `n`. Then sorting by memory usage is default. After that, you only need `top -b -n1 >top.txt`.

Comment: `SHIFT + F` or `SHIFT + M`?